# Update's request for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, updating, database

I can't write update request for my config, can you help me? I have many brackets. I am using '**putty**'.
There is my config:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("567964b88946119e1ebb8bbc"),
"minv": 43,
"maxv": 1000,
"c": "default",
"p": [
      {
       "c": "fragment1",
       "n": [
              {
                "pr": 100,
                "c": "am"
              }
           ]
      },
       {
       "c": "fragment2",
       "n": [
              {
                "pr": 33,
                "c": "am"
              },
                  {
                "pr": 33,
                "c": "pl"
              },
                  {
                "pr": 34,
                "c": "mp"
              }
           ]
      }
]
}
```

My update request does not work:

```
db.trtconfigs.update(
{
'_id':ObjectId('567964b88946119e1ebb8bbc'),
'p.c':'fragment2',
'p.n.c':'am'
},{'$set':{'p.n.pr':20}}
)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You cannot query this structure all in one go since MongoDB does not yet support nested $ operators https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Comment: So, if I understand true - I can't update one parameter, only all child object, can't it?

Comment: atm MongoDB can only update one child object one level deep

Comment: db.adconfigs.update(
{'_id':ObjectId('56815d29e9afcc908ef5af97')},
{'$set':
          {'p.n.0':
                      {"c" : "fragment1","n" :
                                                         [{"pr" : 90,
                                                         "c" : "am"}]
                        }
           }
})

and i have error:
 "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16837,
                "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (p of p.n.0) to traverse the element ..... my config}